# .Net Core API JWT Token Validation

Tags: c#, .net-core, jwt, bearer-token

Implemented the JWT Bearer Token validation in .Net Core WEB API as mentioned below:

```
 services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddJwtBearer(opt =>
                {
                    opt.Audience = Configuration["AAD:ResourceId"];
                    opt.Authority = $"{Configuration["AAD:Instance"]}{Configuration["AAD:TenantId"]}";
                });
```

Doubt here is the above mentioned code will validate only the audience and authority ? or it will validate all the parameters like expiration and signature etc. ?

Do we need to validate the signature explicitly to check the payload has been tampered ?

Comment: Based on my experience it is validating both expiration and signature, but the docs are not that clear: `JWT bearer authentication performs authentication by extracting and validating a JWT token from the Authorization request header.`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you're looking for this:

https://zhiliaxu.github.io/how-do-aspnet-core-services-validate-jwt-signature-signed-by-aad.html

Here zhiliaxu explains in details how and what is actually validated when using `.AddJwtBearer()` and their conclusions are:

> Now it is clear that
>
> - JWT signature is validated without providing any key or certification
>   in our service’s source code.
> - JWT signing key is retrieved from the well-known URL https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/keys, based on
>   JwtBearerOptions.Authority property.
> - The signing key is cached in the JwtBearerHandler singleton instance, and so our ASP.NET Core service only needs to retrieve it
>   once throughout its lifecycle.

Also based on this article we can take a look at the `ValidateToken()` documentation on MSDN: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.identitymodel.tokens.jwt.jwtsecuritytokenhandler.validatetoken?view=azure-dotnet Where you can find the different exceptions the method throws:

- SecurityTokenDecryptionFailedException: token was a JWE was not able to be decrypted.
- SecurityTokenEncryptionKeyNotFoundException: token 'kid' header claim is not null AND decryption fails.
- SecurityTokenException: token 'enc' header claim is null or empty.
- **SecurityTokenExpiredException**: token 'exp' claim is < DateTime.UtcNow.
- SecurityTokenInvalidAudienceException: token 'aud' claim did not match either ValidAudience or one of ValidAudiences.
- SecurityTokenInvalidLifetimeException: token 'nbf' claim is > 'exp' claim.
- SecurityTokenInvalidSignatureException: token.signature is not properly formatted.
- SecurityTokenNoExpirationException: TokenReplayCache is not null and expirationTime.HasValue is false. When a TokenReplayCache is set, tokens require an expiration time.
- **SecurityTokenNotYetValidException**: token 'nbf' claim is > DateTime.UtcNow.
- SecurityTokenReplayAddFailedException: token could not be added to the TokenReplayCache.
- SecurityTokenReplayDetectedException: token is found in the cache.

Comment: Getting the following error while API getting called:

IDX10501: Signature validation failed. Unable to match key:
kid: 'IcMvbl6kv2ZKbug2Ip9MioeTw9A'.
So followed the answer mentioned IDX10501: Signature validation failed. Unable to match keys

But still getting the same exception. Please let me know if something need to be configured in Azure end.

Comment: looks like the authority is not setup properly on the API. Try to navigate to your Authority discovery document: `https://yourauthority.com/.well-known/openid-configuration` you should see a JSON document as response. Inside the JSON document you should see a `jwks_uri` property, something like `https://yourauthority.com/.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks`. Navigate to that URL, and you'll get a json with your authority public key, look at the `kid` property, it should match the one on your token. Enter your token into `jwt.io` website to inspect its contents and compare kids (key ids). BOL

Answer (score 0):

It will validate issuer, audience and lifetime by default. There's a bunch of properties in `TokenValidationParameters`. If you create a new instance of that class, you'll see which fields are set to true/false. Or, you could add the following to your code, breakpoint and investigate yourself.

```
.AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
{ ...
  options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
  {
    ValidateIssuer = false,
    ValidateAudience = false, ...
  }; ..
} ...
```

NB *authority* and *issuer* are pretty much the same concept. Also, mind the difference between `ValidIssuer` and `ValidateIssuer`.