# Validate JWT Token from postman

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt, postman

JWT Token is generated in our application and using the same token within the expiration time I can call my API from postman also. I need to restrict that , so how can we identify if the API call with JWT token is coming from Postman or from browser and how to authenticate it in .net core ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.Net Core API JWT Token Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66891211/net-core-api-jwt-token-validation)

Comment: I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62015405/9070016) can help you. As it says, Postman sends a header named postman-token which can be used to check if the request is sent from Postman.